# Validating URL-Parameter by using Model-Rules CakePHP

Tags: php, validation, cakephp

i just write my first article so please tell me if i've done something wrong!
My Problem: I want to validate data given by url.

**../Logs/requests?from=2011-10-18T16:15:00&to=2011-10-18T16:30:00&fmt=csv**

I have just find out that there is an option to validate with the rules added to the Model.

```
public $validate = array(
    'request_id' => array(
        'alphaNumeric' => array(
            'rule'     => 'alphaNumeric',
            'required' => true,
            'message'  => 'Alphabets and numbers only'
        ),
    )
);
```

Using "**ModelName->set($params)**" in the Controller and after that the "**ModelName->validates()**"-function should deliver the answer if its valid or not. The only differenz between my solution and the solution at  http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation/validating-data-from-the-controller.html
is that my controller using a couple of Models to collect the data for the response.
The problem is that the "**validates()**"-function just return "valid" even if i put in special-characters or other stuff what should be "not valid"-signed by the model-rules.
Help!

Comment: Can you add the content of the `$params` variable to your question? You may need to add a ModelAlias key to the $params array, like this; `$params = array('MyModelAlias' => $params);`

Comment: i've just test it with this "$params = array('request_id'=>'4*G/&2')".

Comment: add: the thing is, i dont want to insert. I just want to validate and select later on. (thanks for the fast response :))

Comment: Did `$params = array('request_id'=>'4*G/&2')` work? If not try this; `$params = array('ModelName' => array('request_id'=>'4*G/&2'));`. You are correct that you are able to manually 'validate' the data, without saving it, however, the model will look inside the 'params' data for a key named after the 'alias' of the model (e.g. 'ModelName') and only validate fields inside that key. If the ModelAlias key is missing, it will find no 'fields' to validate

Comment: Well i have changed it to "$params = array('LogBackend' => array('request_id'=>'4*G/&2'));"

Comment: add: but it still aint work. The "LogBackend" is my real Model where the rules are written according to the exclicid table.

Comment: I added some test-code as an answer so that you can try to narrow down the problem

Comment: The huge problem was i just named my model File "LogBackends" but the class itselft "LogBackend". Sadly the select through the bad named Model File worked so i cant realise that my naming was allready bad.

Comment: add: i've rename "LogBackends" to "LogBackend" and suddenly it work. But i cant imaging why my select worked but the validation through the same Model dont. Where is the differenz?

Comment: If a Model is not present, then CakePHP will 'automagically' create a Model for the database-table. (basically 'new AppModel("tablename")'). Standard methods like 'save()' and 'find()' will therefore work without problems, but all your customizations obviously not. No need to be 'ashamed' though, you're not the first who has been bitten by Cake this way (been there myself) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is *not* an answer, but added to assist the OP;

I've created a test controller/model to test your situation. I deliberately did not extend the 'AppController' / 'AppModel' to remove any code in those from causing problems.

**My test model (app/Model/Some.php)**

```
class Some extends Model
{
    public $name = 'Some';
    public $useTable = 'false';


    public $validate = array(
        'request_id' => array(
            'alphaNumeric' => array(
                'rule'     => 'alphaNumeric',
                'required' => true,
                'message'  => 'Alphabets and numbers only'
            ),
        )
    );
}
```

**My test controller (app/Controller/SomeController.php)**

```
class SomeController extends Controller
{
    public $uses = array('Some');

    public function index()
    {
        $this->autoRender = false;

        $params = array('Some' => array('request_id'=>'4*G/&2'));
        $this->Some->set($params);
        $result = $this->Some->validates();
        debug($result);

        $params = array('Some' => array('request_id'=>'AAAA'));
        $this->Some->set($params);
        $result = $this->Some->validates();
        debug($result);

    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
\app\Controller\SomeController.php (line 32)
false
\app\Controller\SomeController.php (line 37)
true
```

This test setup seems to work as planned, so you may try to test these in your application as well to narrow down the cause of your problem. Maybe some behavior is attached to your AppModel that contains a 'beforeValidate()' callback and disables the validation of the request_id field?